# My question has been marked as a duplicate, but it isn't one

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

My question

[What is the most efficent way to detect even numbers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16969220/1061426)

has been marked as a duplicate. It isn't - at least, it isn't a duplicate of the suggested question here:

[How do I check if an integer is even or odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/160930/1061426)

Which is actually *C* question, and not *Java*. Nor is it about optimisation, although optimisation (qua C) is mentioned a few times.

Comment: I agree. Reopened!

Answer (score 1):

The other question may be about C rather than Java, but its accepted answer does seem to answer your question. It also mentions Java (though lacks the tag for it), which may explain why it was considered a potential duplicate in the first place. It should probably be reopened.

Comment: How does it *seem* to answer my question? Are the C and Java languages now simply interchangable? Furthermore, the answers i received differ largely from the given --c focussed-- answer given there.

Comment: @bharal Perhaps it's just a language thing. When I say it "seems" to answer your question I mean "I can see why somebody might think it answers your question". Anyway, somehow managed to post without actually saying I think your question should be reopened - added that in there.

Comment: Sorry, the just moved desks in the office and the people here keep it *hot*. I'm sweating like a buffalo and not having a bit of a huff, the *seems* on my part was petty.

Comment: @bharal for the question you asked, yes C and Java are interchangeable. Actually, the way you stated it I would say Java is interchangeable with Basic, Prolog, probably F# and especially MUMPS: "**random question time** - what would be the most performant manner to determine an even number using java, and why?..."

Comment: ? the given answers to the question directly compete with the given performant-based answers to the C question, which challenges your opening statement.